# Question about consecutio temporum in fabulae syrae

Tags: syntax, consecutio-temporum, fabulae-syrae

I am reading Fabulae Syrae and I am having some questions about consecutio temporum. I do know the basic rules from familia romana.

However there are some sentences that are causing me some trouble.

1.Fabulae Syrae, XXXII, 2, 74 ss.: “ego enim sum anus, et iam saepe vidi quomodo dei superbos homines puniverint.”

I think that the explanation here is because saepe vidi actually means “scio”, and therefore the subordinate clause goes as if the principal were in present.

2.Fabulae Syrae, XXXII, 3, 195 ss. “Itaque Mercurius ei longam fabulam voce tam suavi narrare coepit ut demum Argus obdormiverit.”

3.FS,XXXII, 5, 305 ss. “Cum enim tales rumores et laudes ad aures Iunonis, reginae deorum, pervenerunt, ea tanta invidia affecta est ut, simul atque haec audivit, Callistum puniendam esse statuerit.”

In these two sentences I think that the result is emphasized as completed, instead of just a tendency of producing the result. I took this from from a certain latin grammar book that I found online (dickinson college):

“c. In clauses of Result, the Perfect Subjunctive is regularly (the Present rarely) used after secondary tenses.

Note 1— This construction emphasizes the result; the regular sequence of tenses would subordinate it.

Note 2— There is a special fondness for the perfect subjunctive to represent a perfect indicative.”

However, specially these two later sentences are causing me trouble. If anyone could help me.

Also a small question: why “Callistum puniendam” and not Callisto puniendam, considering that the accusative, as the book itself says, is Callisto (irregular)?

(Also sorry about my english, it is not my native language).

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem you're having is exactly? What are you expecting to see that you aren't seeing in terms of tenses?

Comment: I just found the answer. The problem was the secondary tense in the first clause with a perfect subjuntive in the subordinated one. But I read in the Companion to Romae Aeterna that this construction emphasizes the result (the imperfect would emphasize just the tendency). Regarding the Callistum puniendam (instead of Callisto), I could not found the answer, but that is not so important as the question about the sequence of tenses. Thank you